# Getting directory path while browsing in c# in a asp web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am programming a test program that is supposed to do a binary compare on video files. The idea is that we have some standard files that we have agreed on being OKAY and then we have some test files that we need to compare with the standard files. Now these files are located on my computer and I therefore need to specify the directory path in which these files are located. So instead of typing it manually in, in the function call, I would like to be able to have a browse button which makes me browse all files on my computer, just as when you open a file in Word or some other application like that.

Now I have tried with OpenFileDialog, but as I have understood this does not Work in a asp webapplication. I have also tried using FileUpload, but this does not seem to Work for me, as I do not want to upload anything.
so my question is are there some alternative to this? Or will I have to just skip this idea?

I hope you can help me!

Regards

Magnus

Comment: When you say the files are located on your computer, do you mean on the computer you are browsing the website from ? In other words, is it the local file system you need to browse ?

Comment: as @Guigui said... Local system? If so, you will have to upload your file first. Besides that, consider calculating CRC instead the more expensive binary compare.

Comment: Yes its in my local filesystem. But I need to get the path for the directory in which the video files are located. FileUpload is only able to give you 1 file at a time, but im interested in getting all files in the directory and retrieveing that path for the directory. And @Gonzix, I know there are better ways to compare the files, but for the moment i go with binary compare as it is so easy to implement.